# Developing Android application with same result as Settings ->Developer options ->Show touch data

Tags: android

I want to develop an independent application to find user touch events(Similar to Settings>Developer Options>Show touch Data).
I have used WindowManager with type set to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and flag set with FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH.
Here i am getting the user touch coordinates but, the touch is not passed on to the below window to open the corresponding touched application.
Please suggests me on how I can get the required result.
Below is the service which does the work.

```
public class HUD extends Service {
    HUDView mView;

//    @Override
//    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
//        return null;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mView = new HUDView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
//              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
//                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mView != null)
        {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
            mView = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

class HUDView extends ViewGroup {
    private Paint mLoadPaint;

    public HUDView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"HUDView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText("Hello World", 5, 15, mLoadPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"X= "+ event.getX()+"Y= "+event.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here i am getting the user touch coordinates but, the touch is not passed on to the below window to open the corresponding touched application.

Fortunately, what you want is not possible on Android 4.0+, for privacy and security reasons. What you are proposing is the malware technique referred to as "tapjacking".

Comment: Yes... This is not possible on Android 4.o+. I got rooted device and want to run the test cases once manually..collect text or content descriptor or resourse id and want to execute same test case automatically using uiautomator tool.Any idea is welcome and thankful other than this approach.